# How to display data from database with onclick in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image]

I have a 'question' table that has the maximum of 10 options with 1 answer type which is declared in the answer_type column.

Firstly, this is my code for displaying dropdowns based on user input in the textbox. And these generated dropdowns contains the questions

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#execute").click(function(){
                var numQ = +$('#q_num').val();
                //Loop--
                for(var ctr=0; ctr < numQ; ctr++){
                    var str = load_questions();
                    $("#divQuestions").append(str);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

After inputting number of questions, its needed to select a category or subcategory to actually generate the number of dropdowns because all questions are under a category or subcategory.

```
function load_questions(){

    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php??main=1&subcategory="+document.getElementById("subcategorydd").value +"&cnt="+document.getElementById("q_num").value,false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("question").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;


}
```

How do I do an onclick trigger that will also display the answer type when i select a question on the dropdown and display it whatever the answer_type is for example checkbox, radiobutton?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
$('#group').change(function (){  
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax.php??main=1&subcategory",     
            data: {main:'1', subcategory:$('#subcategorydd').val(), cnt:$('#q_num').val()},        
            dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned    
            async:false,            
            success: function(response){

                $('#divQuestions').append= response; 
get_table();

            }
        }); 
}); 
</script>
```

and from php side

```
foreach($group->result() as $grp){
            echo '<option value="'.$grp->SubNum.'">'.$grp->SubCategory.'</option>';
        }
```

or you can submit your own query style